# How to bake a cavity map from hi-poly to low-poly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, texture-baking

## Cavity Map Baking from Hi-Poly to Low-Poly

I have a hi-poly mesh object and a low-poly mesh object. The low-poly one is UV-mapped. I created a cavity map material in Cycles for the hi-poly object and I want to bake the color onto the low-poly object. **The problem is that when I try this all the areas where the hi-poly mesh protrudes beyond the low-poly mesh get occluded and don't register in the bake.**

Hi-poly and low-poly objects overlap like so:

[image: Overlapping hi-poly and low-poly mesh objects for baking]

And here is the problematic result:

[image: Color data in the bake is being blocked by the hi-poly mesh]

My Cycles bake settings:

[image: Cycles bake settings]

The material node setup of the low-poly object (bake target):

[image: Bake target material node setup]

My Cycles cavity material (node setup and result on the hi-poly mesh):

[image: Node setup of Cycles cavity material]

[image: Cycles cavity material render preview]

One thing I tried without success was to enable double-sided normals in the Mesh Context options. Is there a better way to do this, or maybe some obvious solution I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

### Update: Fixed!

Here is the result after applying [lemon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24625/lemon)'s answer, just to show for comparison:

[image: The updated fixed result. Problem solved!]

Comment: You could try to give a bit of 'ray distance' in the bake section. If not that, please add you file to the question to understand more the configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "symptom" of a need for 'ray distance' :

[image]

The bake casts rays around the meshes.
If parts of the mesh you want to bake to are too far from the highpoly mesh, the bake will miss them.

Hypothesis : as you use here an emission material that can involve problems for parts of the lowpoly that are inside (not lighted).

Comment: You're right! I should have caught this. Increasing the Ray Distance value in the bake settings was the key. Problem solved. Thanks!