# Surface looks cracked with normal map

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I made a sculpt of a head and then made the retopology. Then I made a normal map bake with selected (sculpt head) to active (low poly head), but the normal map looks all cracked, even with smooth shading in both high res and low res meshes... What I did wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier? If you are, check that the render value is the same as your view value before baking the normal map.

Comment: You may have parts of the high res model outside of the low res one.

Comment: May be related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60285/how-to-bake-a-cavity-map-from-hi-poly-to-low-poly/60286#60286

Comment: You might want to rebake. It looks to me like your normal bake itself is the issue.

Comment: I made many bakes... With different models and different configs... But all look cracked